# Upload image in folder and rename it

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created a interface where user will select and upload image. But how can i rename and save image in server folder(images), and display it again on my image gallery page. My website is developed in asp.net c#.Suggest me some ideas or links to refer.

upload button click code below:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
        FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/uploads/") + fileName);
        Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please post the the upload code as it is now.

Comment: "Who" is the running either IIS EXpress or IIS? Whare are the permissions over this folder ~/uploads?

Comment: Okay, you posted the code for uploading the image. How about the code for your gallery page?

Comment: my gallery page is not yet created,, because i am stuck at renaming and  uploading image. for now i am just using gridview to display images in folder.. thanks

Answer (score 2):

You will need, obviously, a folder somewhere in the website's directory. The user who is running the application pool for the web application will need read/write access to it. Depending on your needs, you may not want this folder to be browsable directly by users (other than the user running the application pool).

You will need to store the new file path somewhere (database, XML file, flat text, etc.) so when the user requests to see the image, you will open this file, and return it in the response stream as its proper type (JPG, GIF, BMP, etc.) so the user is prompted to open it or save it.

Comment: Honestly, I like your first paragraph but not so much your second one paragraph..

Comment: Unless he has more specific requirements, that's how I'd do it. Feel free to edit or add your own answer.

Comment: @Dalorzo If you're going to say you don't like something, it's polite and constructive to say why.

Comment: @FrancisDucharme My apologies I was trying to be constructive. The first paragraph I like it a lot. I just thought the statement on the second one could be misleading. Again my apologies for the misunderstanding but I agree this answer deserves the +1 and I just did.

Comment: @Dalorzo No offense taken.

Answer (score 0):

For Rename and save image in server folder try below code : -

```
 //Get Filename from fileupload control and rename it
 string filename = ((DateTime.Now.ToString().Replace("/", "-")).Replace(":", "")).Replace(" ", "_") + "_" + ((Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName)).Replace(".",".")).Replace(" ","");

 FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/uploads/" + filename));
```